# what's the use of Edge Detection of image?

Tags: edge-detection, canny-operator

After getting edge image using canny, what's the use of edge image?

Is there any use case of edge image?

find object and Segment it from image? or get the sharp,area and perimeter of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the wikipedia,

> Edge detection is the name for a set of mathematical methods which
>   aim at identifying points in a digital image at which the image
>   brightness changes sharply or, more formally, has discontinuities. The
>   points at which image brightness changes sharply are typically
>   organized into a set of curved line segments termed edges.

You can use this to find the interested area of an image by programmatically. For example, you have a lazer image of a indoor floor map and you want to detect the actual area a robot can visit, this will be useful. You can refer google more on this. It's just an example in real world usage.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is much clear now. The robot cannot cross the edge of a wall.

Comment: Absolutely. Here edges of the images shows the walls in the lazer image.